# Infinite Scroll By Paul Irish not working

Tags: jquery

Paul Irish has a plugin infiniteScroll, I have used this before, it won't work for me in this case,

The problem is, the "Show When" thing is negative, please have a look :

[image]

I tried checking for hacks to make this work, I started playing with stuff, and when I touched the `bufferPX`, I get this error if I try using `bufferPx` 2000 - 3000 or bigger.

`TypeError: I.join is not a function`

```
ApplicationHelper.GroupViewMember.MainSection.find('> section.information > section.wall > section.wall_container')
    .infinitescroll({
        navSelector     : "section.navigation_wall",
        nextSelector    : "section.navigation_wall a.next:last",
        itemSelector    : 'section.wall_entry',
        dataType        : 'html',
        bufferPx        :  100,
        debug           :  true,
        pathParse: function(path,page){
            return $(this.nextSelector).attr("href");
        }
    }, function(newElements, data, url){

});
```

The paths are correct, I've tested them.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?  I have the same issue, this plugin is driving me mad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pathParse: function(path,page){
    return $(this.nextSelector).attr("href");
}
```

to

```
path: function(path,page){
    return $(this.nextSelector).attr("href");
}
```

Comment: Hey saw some recent action on this answer. I highly recommend checking out ScrollMagic. http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html